# mediaelement.js: where to place the files

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm not sure where to place the files in the build folder of the download. In the instructions on the homepage they specify relative paths without the folder, e. g. to the js file. Does this mean that the files have to be in the same place as the html or php file? I would like to place them in an extra folder like it is common for js files or images.
Best regards - Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately I didn't figure it out. I created a folder named mediaelement and placed the PHP files that contain a video and the files of mediaelement, there. As I have only a few videos among a lot of other files this is fairly sufficient for me.